# Windows Search Server Express

Tags: c#, .net, search

Is there a .Net api to run queries on Windows Search Server Express 2008?

Answer (score 1):

There is a web service that you could call from .NET: http://www.bolaky.net/post/Using-Microsoft-Search-Server-Express-2008-Web-Services.aspx.